# How to check if the result of a calculation is a natural number?

Tags: floating-point, integer, common-lisp, precision

For another Project Euler struggle (using SBCL 1.3.17) I want to test if a number is a [pentagonal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number). This can be easily tested if the result of

```
(/ (+ 1 (sqrt (+ 1 (* 24 number)))) 6)
```

is a natural number. Ignoring that a natural number is not just an integer because `number` will have only positive values, I started using `intergerp` as a predicate but it did not work out for all tested numbers. So I came up with the following:

```
(defun is-pentagonal-p (number)
  "Returns T if NUMBER is a pentagonal number."
  (multiple-value-bind (n m)
      (floor (/ (+ 1 (sqrt (+ 1 (* 24 number)))) 6))
    (declare (ignore n))
    (when (zerop m) t)))
```

Which worked fine for simple examples, i.e. low number but failed again for high numbers as 1533776805. After quite a while I remembered my old Fortran days and ended up with:

```
(defun is-pentagonal-p (number)
  "Returns T if NUMBER is a pentagonal number."
  (multiple-value-bind (n m)
      (floor (/ (+ 1.0d0 (sqrt (+ 1.0d0 (* 24.0d0 number)))) 6.0d0))
    (declare (ignore n))
    (when (zerop m) t)))
```

which explicitly lower the rounding errors and gives the right results but leaves me with the feeling that I must have missed something much simpler and more lispy. Is this just paranoia?

Comment: `is-<...>-p` is a combination of Lisp-style `-p` suffix and C/Java-style `is` prefix. It will jar the aesthetic feeling of **both** crowds.

Comment: @sds I was not aware of this issue. I cannot remember why I started using this naming scheme for predicates. I definitely do not want to mess with your aesthetic feeling!

Comment: In my solution I used `(defun pentap(x) (subtypep (type-of (/ (1+ (sqrt (1+ (* x 24)))) 6)) 'integer))`, (which worked), but I do not know if this is the best possible test... (or even if it is really correct!).

Comment: @Renzo: this is a very creative way to reimplement [`integerp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_inte_1.htm) :-)

Comment: @sds, very probably, at that time I was starting to re-use lisp after atleast 35 years! :)

Comment: Any idea why you use WHEN?

Comment: @RainerJoswig I was too focused on the other issue to see that it is redundant; good point!

Comment: This is somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39911989/124319

Comment: @coredump Very interesting, thanks for linking the reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Substance

If you use [CLISP](http://clisp.org), you will get

```
(defun pentagonal-side (number)
  (/ (+ 1 (sqrt (+ 1 (* 24 number)))) 6))
(pentagonal-side 51)
==> 6
(pentagonal-side 1533)
==> 32.135838
(pentagonal-side 1533776805)
==> 31977
```

This is because ANSI CL permits [`sqrt`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sqrt_.htm) to return rationals and CLISP does that. Thus you can use [`integerp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_inte_1.htm):

```
(integerp (pentagonal-side 1533776805))
==> T
```

If your lisp ([SBCL](http://sbcl.org)) always returns a float, you need to use *sufficient* [precision](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_dec_fl.htm), e.g.:

```
(pentagonal-side 1533776805d0) ; double-float
==> 31977.0d0
(pentagonal-side 1533776805f0) ; single-float
==> 31977.0
(pentagonal-side 1533776805s0) ; short-float
==> 31976.8s0
```

So, in your case, just pass an appropriate [`float`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_float.htm):

```
(zerop (mod (pentagonal-side 1533776805d0) 1))
==> T
```

### Caveat

It seems that [`single-float`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_short_.htm) is
enough, right?

```
(zerop (mod (pentagonal-side 1533776805f0) 1))
==> T
```

***Nope!***

```
(zerop (mod (pentagonal-side (1+ 1533776805f0)) 1))
==> T
```

### Use "roundtrip"

It is not always easy to guess in advance which float type is appropriate.
Moreover, it is quite imaginable that your `number` will be too large even for your Lisp's [`long-float`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_short_.htm).
(CLISP has [arbitrary float precision](http://clisp.org/impnotes/num-concepts.html#lfd), most lisps do not, and even then you need to decide which precision to use in advance.)

Thus it is easier to stick with integers: make sure that the `pentagonal-side` that you calculate corresponds to the original number via roundtrip:

```
(defun pentagonal-side-int (area)
  (/ (+ 1 (isqrt (+ 1 (* 24 area)))) 6))
(defun pentagonal-area (side)
  (/ (- (* 3 side side) side) 2))
(pentagonal-side-int 1533776805)
==> 31977
(pentagonal-area 31977)
==> 1533776805
(defun pentagonal-number-p (number)
  (let ((side (pentagonal-side-int number)))
    (and (integerp side)
         (= number (pentagonal-area side)))))
(pentagonal-number-p 1533776805)
==> T
(pentagonal-number-p 1533776804)
==> NIL
(pentagonal-number-p 1533776806)
==> NIL
```

## Style

### Names

It is not a very good idea to mix styles. `is-...` is the C/Java
style. `...-p` is the Lisp style. I suggest that you stick with the
latter for your Lisp code.

### [Float contagion](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/12_ada.htm)

No need to convert *all* your numbers to floats:

```
(defun pentagonal-side-double (number)
  (/ (+ 1 (sqrt (+ 1 (* 24 (float number 1d0))))) 6))
```

should make all your calculations
use [`double-float`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_short_.htm).

### Return value

Use `(zerop m)` instead of `(when (zerop m) t)`.
Generally speaking, [`when`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_when_.htm) is
used in "procedural context", when the return value is discarded.
If you use the value, you should use [`if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_if.htm) instead,
and `(if (zerop m) t nil)` is precisely identical to `(zerop m)`.

### [Multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795608/850781)

You should probably
use [`nth-value`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_nth_va.htm) instead
of [`multiple-value-bind`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_multip.htm)
plus [`ignore`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_ignore.htm).

### Standard functions

It is more readable to write `(1+ ...)` than `(+ 1 ...)`.

Comment: That is really very helpful! I wasn't aware of NTH-VALUE.